# Does linux support images in .jpeg format?

Tags: linux, images, jpeg

Does linux support images in .jpeg format? What is the difference if I save my image in `.jpeg` or `.JPEG` or `.jpg` from a linux point of view? Is this case sensitive?

Comment: What do you mean by "support"?

Comment: Not a question?

Answer (score 3):

Quite meaningless question, as Linux is only the kernel of the operating system. I have doubts about a kernel using images. Even the operating system itself does not need images.

But all imaging programs, and all the window managers support jpeg images. They can be named equally .jpeg, .jpg ...

Answer (score 3):

Linux supports jpeg format images. All three variants would be auto-magically recognized to be jpeg images by most modern linux desktop management systems and, for instance, be automagically opened by whatever default image viewing software your system uses.

As noted, linux file names are case sensitive - so it will consider files "foo.jpg" and "FOO.JPG" to be different files.

Answer (score 2):

Another point to consider: The whole .extension format is a windows thing, not a linux/unix thing. *nixs don't care what the file ends with, they read the file type from the header. So if you're having problems opening a .jpg file in Linux the problem is more likely with the file than with the OS.

Assuming you have [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#unix) installed (pretty common), you can just type `identify file.jpg` from the command line and it will tell you what kind of file Linux *thinks* it's looking at. (It's should say something like: `file.jpg JPEG 80x108 80x108+0+0 PseudoClass 256c 19.5kb`)

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of programs running on Linux that can handle JPEG files. It's up to them if they care about file name extension or not and how they do that.

So there are programs that will not recognise *.JPEG* but only *.jpg* as an file name extension for JPEG files, while others will even accept *.mp3* or *.doc* as they just don't care about how you name your files.

Answer (score 0):

Filenames under unixoid operating systems are case-sensitive.